# Extract array encapsulated in an Object

Tags: java, arrays, object

Let's say i have an array encapsulated in an object :

```
String[] strvls = { "Alessio", "Ale" };
Object container = strvls;
```

I want to extract back the array from the container object, how can i do ?

I know that is an array checking in this way :

```
if(container.getClass().isArray()) {
    //Extract the encapsulated array - How ?
}
```

I can't cast into a String array, because I can't know for sure that the type of the array was `String[]` ... So i need to cast into a generic type array, Is it possible in Java ?

Comment: Generic type is not defined for arrays.. You should rather go with `ArrayList`..

Comment: I need a way to discover the size of the encapsulated array ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cast it to `Object[]` array:

```
String[] strvls = { "Alessio", "Ale" };
Object container = strvls;
if (container.getClass().isArray()) {
    Object[] data = (Object[]) container;
    System.out.println(data.length);
}
```

Comment: No, it will print out `2`. The `container` is just a reference which is casted back to `Object[]`. Test it!

Comment: It would have been better the cast to a generic type, however if not possible in Java, your solution do the job. Thanks.

Comment: To be exact it cannot be a generic type, because arrays are not generic in Java.

Comment: You can't construct a generic type array, but you can cast an Object[] to a T[], then it becomes for all purposes a generic array.

Comment: Generics is a different topic, and I wanted to emphasize that.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Karaszi's answer, but a shortcut maybe:

```
if(container instanceof Object[])
  System.out.println("Array size: " + ((Object[])container).length);
```

**Important note:** This will not work for primitive arrays. The code above works since String derives from Object class.

Answer (score 0):

You could have such a method:

```
private static <T> T[] getArray(Object o){
    return (T[]) o;
}
```

This will help work with a generic type and you can keep any 'unchecked' compiler warnings encapsulated in this method. Then you can just do:

```
Object[] array = getArray(container);
```

if you don't know anything about the type or :

```
String[] array = getArray(container);
```

if you know it's a string array.